# How To resolve !empty function issue in php 5.4

Tags: php

I used !empty function multiple places.
But It not woring on php 5.4.
It giving error can not use return type context.
So I create a function for checking null values in php.

```
function not_empty($value) {
    if(trim($value)==null or trim($value) == '0' or trim($value)=="0"){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

So Can I use This Instead of !empty in my project.

Comment: Use `if(!empty(trim($value))` to check empty!!

Comment: @Saty  In PHP 5.4 we could not use expression as input parameter for empty.

Answer (score 2):

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

so no way you can consider your statement to be anywhere close to !empty in php

What you are doing is equivalent only to first condition i.e., empty string.
and also null too. But not false and 0.

I hope u got it

Comment: Actually due to PHPs implicit type conversion the result would be pretty similar. [Example](https://ideone.com/R3J1zB) But still, nothing I would rely on ;)

Comment: very true, that's why i try to use === , == sucks mainly if u are trying to troubleshoot

Comment: yup use only one of them : trim($value) == '0' or trim($value)=="0"                 "" and '' makes difference only with special chars, php variables and other stuffs not with 0.